# Retaining list-ness operations for a data type

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I want to be able to define a custom data type as opposed to using a type alias to ensure that proper values are being passed around, below is a sketch of how that might look,

```
module Example (fromList) where

import Data.Ord (comparing, Down(..))
import Data.List (sort)

data DictEntry = DictEntry (String, Integer) deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Ord DictEntry where
  (DictEntry (word1, freq1)) `compare` (DictEntry (word2, freq2))
    | freq1 == freq2 = word1 `compare` word2
    | otherwise = comparing Down freq1 freq2

data Dictionary = Dictionary [DictEntry] deriving (Show)

fromList :: [(String, Integer)] -> Dictionary
fromList l = Dictionary $ sort $ map DictEntry l
```

However, I'd also like to retain the "list-ness" of the underlying type without having to unwrap and re-wrap `[DictEntry]`, and without having to define utility functions such as `head :: Dictionary -> DictEntry` and `tail :: Dictionary -> Dictionary`. Is that possible? Is there some type class that I could define an instance of or a language extension that enables this?

Comment: Maybe safe casts can help here reducing the wrap/unwrapping. Otherwise, one could define some custom pattern synonyms to allow pattern matching on `Dictionary` similarly to what happens for lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never use `head` and avoid using `tail`, for lists or else. These are unsafe and can always easily be replaced with pattern matching.

But yes, there is a typeclass that supports list-like operations, or rather multiple classes. The simplest of these is [`Monoid`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Monoid), which just implements concatenation and empty-initialisation. [`Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html), allows you to deconstruct containers as if they were lists. [`Traversable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html) additionally allows you to assemble them again as you go over the data.

The latter two won't quite work with `Dictionary` because it's not parametric on the contained type. You can circumvent that by switching to the [“monomorphic version”](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.1.1/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFoldable).

However, I frankly don't think you should do any of this – just use the standard [`Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.9.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#t:Map) type to store key-value associative data, instead of rolling your own dictionary type.

Comment: Regarding `head` & `tail`, I know but it is good that you mention it.

I'll look into `Monoid` and accept your answer if that seems to pan out.

The problem is that it's not a proper map. The data has to be sorted by `snd` primarily, and `fst` secondarily. I could (maybe) use `Data.Set`. But I still want to use list operations. Would `Monoid` (and possibly `Foldable`/`Traversable`) still be suitable?